# Strong Parameters Assignment: Inquiry about params.require

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the below lines of code, and no clue why I am getting Error "ActionController::ParameterMissing in LeaguesController#create param not found: league_name":

```
class LeaguesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @league = League.new
  end

  def create
    @league = League.new(league_params)
    if @league.save
        redirect_to payments_new_url
    else
        render 'new'
    end
  end

  private

  def league_params
    params.require(:league_name).permit(:league_url)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try requiring `league` , as it's the object, and permitting _name and _url

```
params.require(:league).permit(:league_url, :league_name)
```

Comment: That fixed my problems - however, now I have another issue, when I goto enter in data I get the following error: "First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty" Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post your form?

Comment: Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: Sorry - not sure how to format properly yet) New League View

    <%= form_for(@league) do |f| %>

    <%= f.label :league_name %>
    <%= f.text_field :league_name %>
    <br>
    <%= f.label :league_url %>
    <%= f.text_field :league_url %>
    <br>
    <%= f.submit "Create my League" %>
    <% end %>

    <%= link_to "Complete Payment to Start", payments_new_url %>
    <p><%= link_to "Complete Later", '#' %>

Comment: Are you calling this form from the league controller where new is being set properly or from inside another controller?  Try building your form with new instead to test `<%= form_for League.new do |f| %>`